# Gatsby Netlify - functions (AWS) drop nodejs14.x support

Tags: node.js, gatsby, server-side-rendering, netlify, netlify-function

there was a compatibility problem when i tried to deploy Gatsby site with SSR using nodejs14.x for AWS lambda runtime. it shows an error stated `Using an unsupported version of Node.js for functions: nodejs14.x`. I search and noticed nodejs14.x is no longer supported in lambda. So I tried a higher version which is nodejs16.x, the build was fine without errors. but when i run a page with SSR it has a runtime error:

```
Error - The module '/var/task/client/gentek-www/.cache/query-engine/assets/prebuilds/linux-x64/node.abi83.node' was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 83. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. Please try re-compiling or re-installing the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

I thought the version was referring to NODE_VERSION env setting, but the version remains at 83 which meant nodejs14.x. but what i noticed is the node.abi83.node file indicated is from your plugin `@netlify/plugin-gatsby` that only has a specific version that is supported which is `83` (specified in repo in file plugin/src/helpers/files.ts - line 19-23):

```
const DEFAULT_LAMBDA_PLATFORM = 'linux'
const DEFAULT_LAMBDA_ABI = '83'
const DEFAULT_LAMBDA_ARCH = 'x64'

const LAMBDA_PLATFORM = `${DEFAULT_LAMBDA_PLATFORM}-${DEFAULT_LAMBDA_ARCH}`
```

Is there a way to support lambda runtime version nodejs14.x or make new binaries for node16.x/18.x/20.x for lambda? or are there other plugins to use aside from using @netlify/plugin-gatsby?

1. deploy a gatsby site in netlify with SSR page support using NODE_VERSION 14 and AWS_LAMBDA_JS_RUNTIME nodejs14.x
2. you will see an error `Using an unsupported version of Node.js for functions: nodejs14.x`
3. try deploying again but now using NODE_VERSION 16 and AWS_LAMBDA_JS_RUNTIME nodejs16.x
4. successful build
5. run the site, try the page with SSR
6. error will be showing '.../linux-x64/node.abi83.node' was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 83. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93.'

I expected that @netlify/plugin-gatsby supports newer binary versions